# How to fix java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bound must be positive

Tags: java, testing, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have a problem. I want to random click on button "add to cart"
Here is a website: [demo.opencart -compare](http://demo.opencart.com/index.php?route=product/compare)

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Here's my code:

```
List <WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@value = \"Add to Cart\"]"));
            Random gen = new Random();
            WebElement link = links.get(gen.nextInt(links.size()));

            link.click();
```

And I'm getting the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bound must be positive
    at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:388)
    at pages.HomePage.chooseRandomItem(HomePage.java:112)
    at testes.MainPage.chooseRandomItemToCart(MainPage.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:86)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:643)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:820)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1128)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:782)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:632)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1244)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1169)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1064)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:113)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:206)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:177
```

OK, I have found problem. Problem was with main class with test
It didnt work without dependsOnMethod, but it is normal or I have some mistake?

```
'@Test
    public void addToCompare(){
        hp.compareItems();
    }

    @Test
    public void goToComparePage(){
        hp.goToComparePage();


    }
    @Test
    public void usun(){
        hp.findAvailability();

    }

    @Test(dependsOnMethods = { "goToComparePage" })
    public void chooseRandomItemToCart(){
        hp.chooseRandomItem();
    }'
```

Comment: Updated my answer. Don't take it as the fact but that's my thought on the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's exactly what the error is saying: `IllegalArgumentException: bound must be positive`.

Your `gen.nextInt()` is requiring you to pass in a positive numeric value (I'm assuming integer) and yet `links.size()` is return a non-positive value. This could be that `links.size()` is 0 or null, which means it couldn't find any of the elements from line 1 of your code. In that case, the problem is in the following line:

```
List <WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@value = \"Add to Cart\"]"));
```

A couple options at this point:

First, try printing out `links.size()` to see what you get. That'll be the first step.

Second, if it *is* 0 or null, then try debugging your first line of code.

***Update:***

I can't say that it's normal or not because I don't know what your `hp.goToComparePage()` contains. However, if that method is supposed to take you to the compare page where the button that you're trying to implement is located, then it makes sense to actually go to the compare page.

I guess an example would be if you wanted to log into Stack Overflow. You'd obviously want to click "Sign In" button but the thing that has to happen beforehand is to actually go to the Stack Overflow website first, *then* click on the "Sign In" button.

Answer (score 0):

From the `IllegalArgumentException` you're getting, it sounds like `links.size()` is 0. I would ensure your first line is actually returning at least 1 link.